# React native maps view isn't loading on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, maps

I have implemented react-native-maps from here: 
https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps

It was loading the map, my markers were showing correctly until last week. All of a sudden the map view is just blank now. It's just showing a red border and nothing else.

The only thing I have changed last weekend is the name of my project. I have then tried everything I could find online but it's still not working.

Things I have tried:
 1. react-native link
 2. Things mentioned in the issue here: https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/issues/118

I have the recommended stylesheet for map

```
map: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
      }
```

And the render method looks like this:

```
<MapView
            style={ styles.map }
            region={this.state.region}
            showUserLocation={true}
          >
```

I still see a blank screen. I would really appreciate some help here.
Thank you.

Comment: Go through the manual setup instructions and check whether you have all the necessary lines in place. https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md. In my experience it was unreliable to rely on RNPM link.

Comment: I had followed the setup instructions at the beginning. I had to kill the current npm process and then it worked.

Comment: @mayurc did you ever have any luck?

Comment: @PeterChappy yes, it worked when I killed the npm process, reset cache. I had the process running for a long time so these steps worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when I killed the current npm process and reset my cache.